# Data has stopped returning after I added a debounce

Tags: reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I'm making an API call onChange based off the user input. I added a debounce in so it just make the request for every word. I'm doing this in a react final form FormSpy as this has implications for other fields also.

```
import { FormSpy } from 'react-final-form';
import { OnChange } from 'react-final-form-listeners';
import _ from 'lodash';

function Component({
  handleFunction,
  input,
}: {
  handleFunction: any;
  input: any;
}) {
  const debouncedSave = useCallback(
    _.debounce(async (newValue) => await getSuggestedSections(newValue), 1000),
    [],
  );
  return (
    <FormSpy subscription={{ dirty: true, values: true }}>
      {() => (
        <OnChange name="item-name">
          {async (value) => {
            const data = await debouncedSave(value);
            console.log(value);
            console.log(data);
          }}
        </OnChange>
      )}
    </FormSpy>
  );
}
```

When I console log the data, it's coming back undefined, even though I can see the data in the network request.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot await a useCallback function, to get around this issue I would handle the resolution of the promise inside the useCallback and use a use effect that has a dependency of the state that gets updated inside the useCallback.

See below for a runnable example. Ignore the script error, I've included babel runtime via a script tag to allow async functions in code snippets.

```js
async function getSuggestedSections(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(value), 2000));
}

function ExampleComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  const debounceSave = React.useCallback(
    _.debounce(async (newValue) => {
      const data = await getSuggestedSections(newValue);
      setData(data);
      return data;
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  const handleOnChange = async (evt) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setValue(value);
    await debounceSave(value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      console.log(`returned: ${data}`);
      // do stuff with data
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExampleComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```